# Securing REST API with JWT access_token and refresh token approach

Tags: rest, authentication, jwt, passport.js, mern

I'm building a web application using the MERN stack. I've made a REST API to interact with my front-end the usual way,but I'm not able to figure out the best way to build a secure API and overall security of the application.

So far this is what I've tried  

Flow of authenticating a user/request : 
 1. User enters the credentials 
 2. Server responds with `access_token` and `refresh_token`, caching `refresh_token` in redis cache with email as key and `access_token` in localStorage
 3. To access a protected route, user sends the request with `Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}` in request header 
 4. Server checks if the token is valid and not expired, serving the user back with protected resource 
 5. In case, the `access_token` is expired (i've kept the token expiry short eg. 5 min), an action is fired from the front-end (using redux actions), a sample request :

```
POST http://localhost:3000/user/token
Header Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}
Body 
  {
     "email" : "user@example.com"
  }
```

6. Server performs a check in redis cache if the email has `refresh_token`
7. If yes, server responds with updated `access_token`

This is how I'm signing the tokens

```
const signToken = user => {

    let email = user.email;
    let name = user.name;

    const accessToken = JWT.sign({
                            iss : process.env.APP_NAME,
                            sub : user.id,
                            email : email,
                            name : name
                        }, JWT_SECRET, {
                            expiresIn : 300
                        });

    const refreshToken = JWT.sign({
                                iss : process.env.APP_NAME,
                                sub : user.id,
                                email : email,
                                name : name
                            }, REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, {
                                expiresIn : '30d'
                            });

    // Save to redis cache
    REDIS_CLIENT.set(email, refreshToken);

    return {accessToken, refreshToken};
}
```

and for getting new `access_token`

```
// Refresh token
const refreshToken = (req, res, next) => {

    const extractToken = req.headers['authorization'];
    const token = extractToken.split(' ')[1];

    if (!token) {
        return res.status(403).json({
            message : 'Unauthorized'
        });
    }

    REDIS_CLIENT.get(req.body.email, (err, cachedToken) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).json({message : 'Something went wrong'});

        if (cachedToken == null) {
            return res.status(403).json({message : 'Unauthroized'});
        } else {

            JWT.verify(cachedToken, REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, rt) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).json({message : 'Something went wrong'})
                } else {
                    // Generate a new access token here
                    const newAccessToken = JWT.sign({
                                iss : process.env.APP_NAME,
                                sub : rt.sub,
                                email : rt.email,
                                name : rt.name
                            }, JWT_SECRET, {
                                expiresIn : 300
                            });

                    return res.json({
                        "accessToken" : newAccessToken
                    });
                }

            });

        }
    });
}
```

Is this approach secure? If not, what are some good ways to design the authentication flow if stack is MERN. Upon searching the internet, many have advised to set short expiry in `access_token` and use the `refresh_token` to generate new `access_token`, but I haven't found how to logout user on inactivity? What if attacker gets the expired token and email id, and generates the new access_token? How will be the oAuth integration?

PS : Sorry for putting so much here, came here after a lot of searches on the internet but found nothing much

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this/find any good resources?